# Aggregate values on lists of dicts based on key in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to get the aggregation of 2 different lists, where each element is a dictionary with 2 entries, month and value.

So the first list looks like this:

```
[{
    'patient_notes': 5,
    'month': datetime.date(2017, 1, 1)
}, {
    'patient_notes': 5,
    'month': datetime.date(2017, 2, 1)
}, {
    'patient_notes': 5,
    'month': datetime.date(2017, 5, 1)
}, {
    'patient_notes': 5,
    'month': datetime.date(2017, 7, 1)
}, {
    'patient_notes': 5,
    'month': datetime.date(2017, 8, 1)
}, {
    'patient_notes': 5,
    'month': datetime.date(2017, 12, 1)
}]
```

Second list is:

```
[{
    'employee_notes': 4,
    'month': datetime.date(2017, 2, 1)
}, {
    'employee_notes': 4,
    'month': datetime.date(2017, 3, 1)
}, {
    'employee_notes': 4,
    'month': datetime.date(2017, 4, 1)
}, {
    'employee_notes': 4,
    'month': datetime.date(2017, 8, 1)
}, {
    'employee_notes': 4,
    'month': datetime.date(2017, 9, 1)
}, {
    'employee_notes': 4,
    'month': datetime.date(2017, 10, 1)
},  {
    'employee_notes': 4,
    'month': datetime.date(2017, 12, 1)
}]
```

So I need to build a new list that contains the sum of both list per month, something like this:

```
[{
    'total_messages': 14,
    'month': '2017-01-01'
}, {
    'total_messages': 14,
    'month': '2017-02-01'
}, {
    'total_messages': 14,
    'month': '2017-03-01'
}, {
    'total_messages': 14,
    'month': '2017-04-01'
}, {
    'total_messages': 14,
    'month': '2017-05-01'
}, {
    'total_messages': 14,
    'month': '2017-06-01'
}, {
    'total_messages': 14,
    'month': '2017-07-01'
}, {
    'total_messages': 14,
    'month': '2017-08-01'
}, {
    'total_messages': 14,
    'month': '2017-09-01'
}, {
    'total_messages': 14,
    'month': '2017-10-01'
}, {
    'total_messages': 14,
    'month': '2017-11-01'
}, {
    'total_messages': 14,
    'month': '2017-12-01'
}]
```

I first tried with zip but this only works if first 2 list are equal size. Then I tried with [itertools.izip_longest] but this has problems if lists are equal size but different months...I cannot simply aggregate those...I need to aggregate matching months only

Counter also is great for this, but I cannot change the keys names of original lists...any ideas?

Comment: Add the code that you tried

Comment: How are you adding the `patient_notes` and `employee_notes`?

Comment: Looks like a problem for Pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `defaultdict` to create a counter.  Go through each item in the first list and add the `patient_notes` value to the dictionary.  Then go through the second list and add the `employee_notes` values.

Now you need to encode your new defaultdict back into a list in your desired format.  You can use a list comprehension for that.  I've sorted the list by month.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(int)

for d in my_list_1:
    dd[d['month']] += d['patient_notes']
for d in my_list_2:
    dd[d['month']] += d['employee_notes']

result = [{'total_messages': dd[k], 'month': k} for k in sorted(dd.keys())]
>>> result
[{'month': datetime.date(2017, 1, 1), 'total_messages': 5},
 {'month': datetime.date(2017, 2, 1), 'total_messages': 9},
 {'month': datetime.date(2017, 3, 1), 'total_messages': 4},
 {'month': datetime.date(2017, 4, 1), 'total_messages': 4},
 {'month': datetime.date(2017, 5, 1), 'total_messages': 5},
 {'month': datetime.date(2017, 7, 1), 'total_messages': 5},
 {'month': datetime.date(2017, 8, 1), 'total_messages': 9},
 {'month': datetime.date(2017, 9, 1), 'total_messages': 4},
 {'month': datetime.date(2017, 10, 1), 'total_messages': 4},
 {'month': datetime.date(2017, 12, 1), 'total_messages': 9}]
```

Comment: Pretty neat! Didn't think about using a dict to aggregate the values, thanks @Alexander

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d_dict = defaultdict(int)
for k,v in [ i.values() for i in l1 + l2 ]:
    d_dict[k] += v
[ {'month':i.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),'total_messages':j} for i, j in sorted(d_dict.items()) ]
```

Output:

```
[{'month': '2017-01-01', 'total_messages': 5},
 {'month': '2017-02-01', 'total_messages': 9},
 {'month': '2017-03-01', 'total_messages': 4},
 {'month': '2017-04-01', 'total_messages': 4},
 {'month': '2017-05-01', 'total_messages': 5},
 {'month': '2017-07-01', 'total_messages': 5},
 {'month': '2017-08-01', 'total_messages': 9},
 {'month': '2017-09-01', 'total_messages': 4},
 {'month': '2017-10-01', 'total_messages': 4},
 {'month': '2017-12-01', 'total_messages': 9}]
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the `for k,v` part --- wouldn't `values()` return a list of numbers?

Comment: @patrick - lf you observe, the input list is list of dictionaries... i.values()  will get the values for each dictionary inside list... [(date1,num1),(date2,num2).... etc.]

Comment: And from the OPs output, we can achieve it by just applying logic with Values ignoring dict keys.